how to set the size of Button which is placed in GridLayout(4,4) in simple java awt? ill use setMinimum(), setMaximum(),setPrefersize(). Won't work
when i trying to set the size of Button. which is placed in GridLayout(4,4). i'll used setPrefer(), setMinimum(), setMaximum(). it wont work; then how to set the size of Buttons in awt java. Give the answer in simple java code

If you are new to java, please know that awt is very old, ancient, better swing or even javafx (now openjfx).


Don't bold all the text when asking a question. Bold is used to highlight certain words, not all the words. 2) The GridLayout will resize components to fill all the available space. One solution is to wrap the panel in another panel using a layout manager that will respect the size of components. For example a panel with a FlowLayout. Read the Swing tutorial on Layout Managers for more information.

